# Jackson serialize problem in @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: json, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

I have the following situation:

```
//--class user --
private ....

@OneToMany(targetEntity = UserRoles.class, mappedBy = "iduser", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<UserRoles> userRoleList = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToOne(targetEntity = Login.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "iduser", referencedColumnName = "iduser")
@JsonManagedReference
private Login login;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "n_gruppi_user", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "iduser") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "idgruppo") })
@JsonManagedReference
List<Gruppi> groups = new ArrayList();
```

next class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gruppi")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)

@Data
public class Gruppi implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long idgruppo;
private long iduser;
private String tipo;
private String nome_gruppo;
private String pass_gruppo;
private String email_gruppo;
private String descr_gruppo;
private Timestamp data_creazione;


@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
@JsonBackReference
List<User> users_group = new ArrayList<>();
```

when i run application, it's all ok and i get
[image]
When i serialize my object User, jackson serializes everything except users_group, that's because I'm using @JsonBackReference. But if don't use @JsonBackReference circularity problems arise.How can I get users_group serialization too ?? I need it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both classes you should have defined some `ID` property, we can use to identify objects in data base. We can use it to help `Jackson` to identify instances in runtime. You can remove `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` and instead use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo` annotation:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "iduser")
class User {
...
}
```

and

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "idgruppo")
class Gruppi {
...
}
```