# StackOverflowError after adding user field

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@ToString(exclude = "password")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "user_to_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

in my code users have a role field, I decided to add users field to the roles entity.I need this in order not to contact the database every time to search for users, if there are roles. I want to get a list of id of users who have this role, without the rest of the fields. As I understand it, lazy loading will help me with this, but I'm not sure(I haven't had time to test yet).
When I try to log in, I get the following error, I suppose it is due to spring security, I don't understand

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_to_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<User> users;
}




java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.TurboFilterList.getTurboFilterChainDecision(TurboFilterList.java:49) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getTurboFilterChainDecision_0_3OrMore(LoggerContext.java:269) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callTurboFilters(Logger.java:751) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isDebugEnabled(Logger.java:469) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger.isEnabledFor(SLF4JLogger.java:211) ~[log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger.isEnabled(SLF4JLogger.java:121) ~[log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.isEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1513) ~[log4j-api-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
at org.jboss.logging.Log4j2Logger.doLog(Log4j2Logger.java:52) ~[jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar:3.4.1.Final]
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.debug(Logger.java:531) ~[jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar:3.4.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2161) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at dev.redlab.mgs.backoffice.model.entities.Role.hashCode(Role.java:25) ~[main/:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:340) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:613) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:221) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:336) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2161) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at dev.redlab.mgs.backoffice.model.entities.User.hashCode(User.java:15) ~[main/:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:340) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:613) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:221) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:336) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2161) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at dev.redlab.mgs.backoffice.model.entities.Role.hashCode(Role.java:25) ~[main/:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:340) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:613) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:221) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:336) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2161) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at dev.redlab.mgs.backoffice.model.entities.User.hashCode(User.java:15) ~[main/:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:340) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:613) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:221) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:336) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.endLoading(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishLoadingCollections(AbstractRowReader.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2161) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.17.Final.jar:5.4.17.Final]
```

this is repeated a huge number of times, I did not insert. thanks in advance
there is a user_to_role table in the database and an entry in it

Comment: Do you also have a `@ToString` annotation on `Role`?

Comment: Read about `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`: [Jackson – Bidirectional Relationships](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion). See also: [Jackson/Hibernate, meta get methods and serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383889/jackson-hibernate-meta-get-methods-and-serialization), [Jackson serialize problem in @ManyToMany relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392551/jackson-serialize-problem-in-manytomany-relationship)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code uses the annotation @Data, which generates hashCode and ToString methods  and this structure leads to Hibernate stuck. in my case I just added the exclusion parameters, like `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="dependent_list")`

Answer (score 0):

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_to_role",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Can you try like this in the User entity, and the Vice Versa(inverseJoin and join based on entity) on Role Entity side also.

And please ensure that either of the entity should load/Fetch this property in a Lazy mode otherwise there will be an infinite loop of references that are ready to fetched.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

The above should be done on at least one of the cross referenced entities.

Comment: @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_to_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<User> users;

 on role entity

Comment: @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "user_to_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;